# What is the syntax for target multiple tags in css

Tags: html, css

How should one go about targeting multiple html tags at once in css? Is it essentially just:

```
h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 {
     font-weight:lighter;
}
```

Comment: The selectors should be separated by commas.. so: `h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { ... }` http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#grouping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need commas like this:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
font-weight:lighter;
}
```